# Mac OS Mojave "open" command very slow

Tags: macos-mojave

Sometime in the last few months, I can't pin it down precisely, the Mac OS "open" command has become incredibly slow.  If, say, I have a pdf in a directory, and type at the prompt "open file.pdf", or even "open -a Skim file.pdf", it takes minutes before the viewer actually opens.  I have no idea what it could be doing, this used to be pretty much immediate.

Any advice on how to track this down?  It would appear that some update, which I install automatically, made something go wrong, but unfortunately I can't be more precise than that.

Bob Harper

Comment: Have you upgraded from previous version of MacOS? If so, try installing Mojave from scratch, that will solve it :)

Comment: Rebuild Launch Services cache?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and belongs on [su], though it's probably off-topic there, too.

Comment: Apologies, where would it be on-topic?  I'd like to resolve this problem.

Comment: Well, I would try on [su].

Comment: How would I rebuild the Launch Services cache?  That has the right "ring" to it, so it's worth a try.